# Query result Result ignored

Tags: symfony, doctrine-query

I have a function where i do theses 2 requests :

```
$in = $this->em->getRepository("QueensBundle:CaisseMvtArticle")
        ->findOneBy(array('ville_id'=>$lieu,'nature'=>'out','scoope'=>'central'));

$out = $this->em->getRepository("QueensBundle:CaisseMvtArticle") 
        ->findOneBy(array('ville_id'=>$lieu,'nature'=>'out','scoope'=>'ville'));
```

when i execute it and try to read the second request result, the variable $out has the same data as the first ($in). when i remove the first query($in) , the $out variable has the expected datas. I don't understand this. What can i do to get the two requests executed and get good results for each one ?

Comment: It looks like it should work.  Are you really sure $in === $out?  Maybe something else is wrong and it just looks like they are the same.

Comment: It's solved. my laying table is a view, i had to set set Id, columns in my Entity, Thanks !